# Reformatting and printing to PDF, text in Vim

Tags: vim

When hardcopy-ing to PDF, is there a way to detect what is the maximum `textwidth` possible for an A4 format, taking into account the current font size in Vim?

*In short, I have a long document which I want to reformat and print out, while using as much paper space as possible. So far I've always had to try it out, and it's a pain.*

Comment: Is your documentation plain text or is it in some lightweight markup language that could be converted by an external tool (e.g. Markdown converted to PDF by Pandoc)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adjusting the margins in your [`printoptions`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/print.html#popt-option)? I don't think `textwidth` has any affect on the hardcopy page. Print font/size should also be separate from hardcopy font/size.

Comment: I don't see how printoptions could help. If you mean wrapping I don't want the text wrapped, just to see what is the maximum number of characters per line for a designated font size.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way that I know of, but if you copy and paste the following lines into your text:

```
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111

000000000111111111122222222223333333333444444444455555555556666666666777777777788888888889999999999000000000011111111112222222222333333333344444444445

123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890
```

...and then print it to PDF, you will be able to easily see where it wraps.  (Just read the digits vertically downward.)